# Multi line variable in batch file echoing back hidden spaces in printer permission script

Tags: batch-file, cmd, subinacl

I sat down hours ago to write a seemingly straight forward 1 or 2 liner to add permissions to every print queue on a computer using a combination of WMIC and subinacl.exe.

```
@echo off
pushd %~dp0
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "skip=1 tokens=*" %%a in ('wmic printer get name') do (
set "_var=%%a" do (
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=" %%g in ("!_var!") do (
echo subinacl /printer "%%g" /grant=Everyone=F
    )
)
pause
```

Turns out it aint so easy at all! This is as close to working I can get, but the echoing  reveals extra spaces and quotations in the wrong places, causing sunbinacl to fail with printer name errors, this is the output: -

```
subinacl /printer "Canon MG5300 series Printer WS  " /grant=Everyone=F
subinacl /printer "testfff                         " /grant=Everyone=F
subinacl /printer "OneNote (Desktop)               " /grant=Everyone=F
subinacl /printer "Microsoft Print to PDF          " /grant=Everyone=F
subinacl /printer "Canon MG5300 series Printer     " /grant=Everyone=F
subinacl /printer "444444444444444                 " /grant=Everyone=F
Press any key to continue . . .
```

This is how it should look for subincal to correctly apply the permissions...

```
subinacl /printer "Canon MG5300 series Printer WS" /grant=Everyone=F
subinacl /printer "testfff" /grant=Everyone=F
subinacl /printer "OneNote (Desktop)" /grant=Everyone=F
subinacl /printer "Microsoft Print to PDF" /grant=Everyone=F
subinacl /printer "Canon MG5300 series Printer" /grant=Everyone=F
subinacl /printer "444444444444444" /grant=Everyone=F
Press any key to continue . . .
```

How can I alter my script to achieve the correct spacing and quotations around the printer name like above. I believe I should be able to do this, no problem, but I'm missing something - probably obvious.

I have a feeling it has to do with taking the parsed WMIC output being set as a variable in one block, where perhaps each line of the variable (printer queue) needs to be sent into the subinacl command one by one.

Usually I can get to where I want to be in these instances but cant surpass this issue. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `wmic` formats the strings for a nice table output on screen by filling too short strings with spaces.

Easy to avoid. Just change the formatting.

Change `... ('wmic printer get name') ...` to

```
... ('wmic printer get name /format:list') ...
```

You don't need to set a variable to use in the inner loop, you can just use the metavariable from the outer loop (you need the second loop though to get rid of the ugly `wmic` format with a `CRCRLF` line ending. There are other methods, but a `for` loop is the most general and safest):

```
@echo off
pushd %~dp0
setlocal 
for /f "tokens=1* delims==" %%a in ('wmic printer get name /format:list ^|find "="') do (
  for /f "tokens=1,* delims=" %%g in ("%%b") do (
    echo subinacl /printer "%%g" /grant=Everyone=F
  )
)
```

Comment: I've seen some WMIC commands with wild unicode outputs so when the font and text looked ok in this case I completely over looked formatting as culprit. Got stuck in a dead end loop trying to clear them using tokens, delims and extra variables! Thanks very much, lessoned learned!

Comment: Piping to `find` converts to ASCII, but doesn't remove the `CRCRLF`. Parsing or setting to a variable removes `CRLF` and leaves the string with an annoying `CR` at the end. The line ending can be removed with a `for` loop, but it keeps the UTF16 format. So using a combination to get "the best from both worlds"

Answer (score 0):

[untested]

```
...
  for /f "tokens=1,* delims=" %%g in ("!_var!") do (
  set "_printer=%%g"
  call :trim
  echo subinacl /printer "!_printer!" /grant=Everyone=F
    )
)
pause

goto :eof

:trim
if "%_printer:~-1%"==" " set "_printer=%_printer:~0,-1%"&goto trim
goto :eof
```

- assign printername to `_printer` and execute `:trim` as a subroutine (hence the `goto :eof` which prevents flow-through to the subroutine)

`:trim` simply checks the last character of `_printer` and if it is a space, trims it off and repeats the operation until the trailing spaces are gone.

Repeat : ***untested***

Answer (score 0):

To fulfil your [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd) tag, and one or two liner requirements, here's a single line example which can be run directly in a Command Prompt, (cmd.exe), window:

```bash
for /f tokens^=6^ delims^=^" %g in ('wmic printer get name /format:mof 2^>nul') do @subinacl /printer "%g" /grant=everyone=F
```

*For robust and efficient code, you should, however, use the fully qualified and absolute paths, with extensions, for both of your executable utilities.*